# Migrating my app to 64 bit with parse and I get this link error that is driving me crazy

Tags: ios, parse-platform, 64-bit

Migrating my iOS app to 64 bit using Parse and Bolts and I get this link error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFCancellationTokenSource", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Parse(PFQuery.o)
>         objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you figured it out?

Comment: Have you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Add Bolts.framework from Facebook 
also if you have defined in your project BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException, you need to remove it

*Note: download the latest SDKs from FB and Parse